# How do i walk a tree with multiple types efficiently?

Tags: c++, algorithm, containers, complexity-theory

We all know we should use a list, deque or another object instead of using the classic link-list however the way i am thinking is link-list like.

I have a type which i'll call ABC. I have access to everything through `ABC root`. The type ABC can hold 0 or many ABCs within. It can also hold type DE, FGH, D, E, F, G, H. DE can also hold type D and E. FGH can hold FG, F, G, H. FG holds... you get the idea. Those objects can also hold 0 or many of that type and its subtypes.

The problem i am facing is how do write this in a way that if i am in type F i can call parent() and walk my way back to the root type ABC? Lets actually forget about the types FOR NOW and assume everything is the type BASE. How would i write this tree in C++? I was thinking of doing something like this

```
class Base{
    deque<Base*> children
    Base*parent;
}
```

But this felt like a link list. Mostly because walking up the tree is just looking at pointer after pointer which is exactly what a link list does and walking down a tree is pointer after deque of pointers. Is there some efficient way of holding trees and walking it? My app is CPU and memory bound so i am not sure which tradeoff i want to make. How do i hold this data?

Comment: I don't get your question. If you need to be able to walk up your tree, you'll need to store something that links up (pointer or reference). No way around that. If I read your questions literally, you're asking "how do I walk a tree" and "how do you build a tree" which are both very broad and have hundreds if not thousands of answers already here and elsewhere. And please, capitalize the **I** . **I** is always written in uppercase.

Answer (score 1):

> We all know we should use a list or another object instead of using a
>   classic link-list

Uh, wot?

Linked lists don't have the most uses evar, but when you need something like what you have, which is a DAG, then there's pretty much no other way to do it.

Just use the pointers.